# What are eigenvalues and eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

What are eigenvalues, eigenstates and eigenfunctions in quantum-mechanics? Please explain in-depth if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, these are simply mathematics termes. When an operator operates on a function, the result is also a function. In the language of mathematics:

A f = a g

Where f and g are in generally different functions, a is a constant and A is an operator. 
Sometimes, the result of this operation might be the same function (g=f) multiplied with a constant. Functions f with this property are called eigenfunctions of the operator A. In other words, equation:

Af=af

is called eigenvalue equation and the constant a is called eigenvalue of the operator A.

Coming to quantum mechanics, this type of equation is important because any general function could in principle be expressed in terms of all the fi -eigenfunctions of the operator A.

For more detailed version of answer on your question I invite you to read postulates of quantum mechanics. I think they are not too long and should be able to satisfy your curiosity :) .